# How to display image in an infoBox in shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to put an image inside the `infoBox` of a shinyApp.

I am getting this error:

> Error in shinyUI(dashboardPage, dashboardHeader("ABC"),
>   dashboardBody(fluidPage(h1("type"),  :    unused arguments
>   (dashboardHeader("ABC"), dashboardBody(fluidPage(h1("type"),
>   mainPanel(tabsetPanel(tabPanel(h1("summary"), infoBox("BCD", a,
>   div(img(src = "ribbon.PNG", width = 100), style = "text-align:
>   center;"))))))))

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
a  = 45
ui < - shinyUI(dashboardPage,
           dashboardHeader("ABC"),
           dashboardBody(fluidPage(h1("type"),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel(h1("summary"), 
                         infoBox("BCD", a, div(img(src = "ribbon.PNG", 
                         width = 100), style = "text-align: center;"))))))))
server <- shinyServer({})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an image `img.png` in the `www` folder and then the code below works :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
a <- 45

ui <-   shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "ABC"),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
            fluidPage(
                infoBox("BCD", a, div(img(src = "img.png", width = 100), style = "text-align: center;"))
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```